# Trying to update a property on an Object via Ajax.BeginForm, but every other property on Object is null after submit

Tags: html, ajax, post, razor, ajax.beginform

I'm trying to update the PaymentNotificationEmail and only the PaymentNotificationEmail using Razor Code below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "PaymentLandingPage", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    }))
    {
        <table class="PEmailFields">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="float:left;">
                        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                            <li><span id="PEmaillbl">Payment Notification Email:</span></li>
                            <li><br /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;">
                        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PrimaryNamedInsured)
                            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentNotificationEmail, new { @id = "PEmailtxbx", placeholder = "Example: ppp@test.com", maxlength = "100", style = "margin-left:25px;min-width:530px;", Value = Model.PrimaryNamedInsured.PrimaryEmail })</li>
                            <li><span id="PEmaildsclmr" data-PEmailValue="@Model.PaymentNotificationEmail"><i style="margin-left:190px;font-size:small;">* This email address is used for payment notifications.</i></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input style="margin-left:35%;" type="submit" value="Save Email" />
    }
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I get to the Controller, The Object only has PaymentNotificationEmail. Every thing else on the object is Null.

How can I update PaymentNotificationEmail without losing The information that is already in @Model?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. You also have an input for `PrimaryNamedInsured`, so that will be posted as well and bind to you model as well. But you have not shown you models or controller methods (are there other properties in the model that you want to be bound and if so why?). And as a side note NEVER set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. You set the value of `PrimaryNamedInsured` in the GET method before you send it to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and troubleshooting, we redesigned the whole thing and the question became irrelevant.  The ultimate Answer was we had a bad design to begin with.